# Hint to derive equivalent sum form

Tags: summation, arithmetic

I'm currently struggling to find a way to derive an equivalent formula from the sum of two sums.

I'm looking at this problem
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (n-k-1)! + (-1)^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k} (n-k-2)! + (-1)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}(n-k-1)!
$$

I get as far as merging the right hand side into one sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left(\binom{n}{k}(n-k-1)!+\binom{n-1}{k}(n-k-2)!\right)+(-1)^{n-1}n 
$$
$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k\left(\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(n-k-1)! + \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}(n-k-2)!\right) + (-1)^{n-1} n
$$
That's the point I am at right now. I would appreciate a tiny hint on how to proceed to derive the desired form.

Comment: **Hint:** Use the fact that $n! = n \cdot (n-1)!$. You can apply this to the $(n-k)!$ and $(n - k - 1)!$ terms.